# How to specify the inferred return type of a function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
type FnReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never;
export const noExcept = <T>(
  fn: (() => T) | (() => Promise<T>) | Promise<T>
): FnReturnType<typeof fn> extends Promise<any> ? Promise<T | null> : T | null => {
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    try {
      const result = fn();
      if (result instanceof Promise) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => result.then(resolve, () => resolve(null))) as any;
      }
      return result as any;
    } catch (e) {
      return null as any;
    }
  } else if ('then' in fn) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => fn.then(resolve, () => resolve(null))) as any;
  }
  return null as any;
};
```

which accepts

- A promise
- A function that returns a promise
- A normal function

And returns null if the promise (either raw, or returned by calling the input) throws, or if the input throws, and returns the input otherwise.

This means, depending on the input, it can return a promise or not.

I'm trying to get the Typescript signature of this function to be correct, and it is just not there. How can I fix it? I've pasted my attempt above.

Comment: You haven't really stated the problems you are facing, but running it in playground I noticed that `typeof fn === 'function'` doesn't narrow out the promise and also that 'then' in fn` didn't result in `fn.then` being allowed.  These are limitations in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use function overloads to handle each case seperatly like following:

```
export function noExcept<T>(fn: () => T): T | null;
export function noExcept<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T | null>;
export function noExcept<T>(fn: Promise<T>): Promise<T | null>;
```

more details you can find on Typescript documentation about [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html)